# Create a Restful web service to Control the operations mentioned in JConsole

Tags: web-services, rest, jmx, jconsole, jmx-ws

As a Application Support Analyst, I need to monitor and control my application using Jconsole so there are some operations(i.e some JMX operations related to my application) which I can control it in using Jconsole,same operation I need to control it by exposing/ using a Restful web service. Can you any one help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://jolokia.org.
 It is a JMX providing RESTful service you can embed in your app.